# How to use xdmp.Spawn() to do a temporal delete in MarkLogic 9?

Tags: javascript, json, marklogic, marklogic-9, temporal

My data set is very huge and I have a search query (cts.uris) constructed with particular parameters that returns me the sequence of all the URIs of the documents. I want to use a xdmp.spawn() with temporal.documentDelete() so that I can delete all of my data from the search results.

When I use temporal.documentDelete() on a loop directly it gets timed out because of the said huge data set. The function can contain 2 parameters: Collection name & directory name.

I'm using JS and my documents are all JSONs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend using an external tool to orchestrate the batching up, and processing. Tools like NiFi could work for this, but Corb2 is also good option. Here some relevant resources on that tool:

- [CoRB – Free MarkLogic NoSQL database tutorial](https://mlu.marklogic.com/ondemand/65ca4c93)
- [Corb2 - MarkLogic Community](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/corb/)
- [Using CoRB to batch process your content: a getting started](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/62/19/using-corb-to-batch-process-your-content-a-getting-started-guide)

HTH!